# Did official React Native CLI Quickstart guide. Won't start, stuck at Loading dependecy graph

Tags: react-native

I'm on the latest Windows 10 version with React Native 0.60. Did the official React Native CLI Quickstart guide. Running "react-native run-android" creates another command line window, which is doing the Metro Bundler stuff and Loading dependecy graph... never finishes. Once it reaches 4GB of memory usage it just closes automatically. I think it is some kind of a memory leak. A small example program doesn't need many resources. Anybody saw anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

1. I had to do what cbpetersen wrote here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11696
2. Had to downgrade to node.js 12.4 because of this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25698